# http package get wrong image url from api in flutter

Tags: node.js, image, api, http, flutter

i have a flutter application connected with API, when i make a Get request using http package in flutter, it retrieve all data without any problem, except the images url: for example this the url of image from browser:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\\139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg
```

but from response in flutter its like this:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload%5C139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg
```

as you can see, the problem after upload section in url>>>>

this is the code for image in API

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
   cb(null, 'upload');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, file.originalname);
         }
});
const filter = (req, file, cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png"){
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    filter: filter
});
app.post('/service' ,upload.single('file'));
app.use('/upload', express.static('upload'));
```

and this to get all data including images url:

```
 getAllServices : async (req, res)=>{
        try {
        const result = await SERVICES.find();
        res.json(
            {result : result.map(result =>{
                return {
                    id : result._id,
                    name : result.name,
                    file : 'http://192.168.43.106:3000:3000/'+result.file,
                    desc : result.desc,
                    price : result.price,
                    cat : result.cat,
                    url : 'http://192.168.43.106:3000:3000/service/'+result._id
                }
            })
            });
        }catch(err){result.json(err)}
        
        },
```

and in flutter side i am using this code to get data:

```
class ServicesState extends State<Services>{
  getCategories() async {
    var res = await http.get("http://192.168.43.106:3000/service/cat/${widget.cid}");
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
      return jsonObject['result'];
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.name), actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: ()=>{
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/cat'),
      },)],),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCategories(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.data != null){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return ListTile(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ServiceDetails(
                        details: ServicesModel(
                          id: snapshot.data[index]['id'],
                          name: snapshot.data[index]['name'],
                          desc: snapshot.data[index]['desc'],
                          price: snapshot.data[index]['price'],
                          file: snapshot.data[index]['file']
                        ) ,)));
                    },
                      leading:Image.network(snapshot.data[index]['file']),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['name']),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['price']),
                  );
                },
              );
            }else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
```

just remember please all data fetched without any problem except image url>>>>

and this the error that i got: as you see, i got all data from api like below>>

```
I/flutter (15351): [{id: 5ef73963f8f4f552704eb5fb, name: momen, desc: uni, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111}, {id: 5ef755aa9011f235d007d432, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef755bb9011f235d007d433, name: c11, desc: d11, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11}, {id: 5ef755e59011f235d007d434, name: c11, desc: d11, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11}, {id: 5ef755f39011f235d007d435, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef7567b215f705ec00d439a, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef759d4167fb241b82fcfcd, name: newcat, desc: unimmm5n, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg}, {id: 5ef75ae8d313d64f4cecbfc5, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\Capture.PNG}, {id: 5ef75f15231fcc4edc13b3b9, name: c1y, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png}, {id: 5efa29ba17c0672b88fb6ae8, name: catauth, desc: auth cat desc, img: http://192.168.43.106:30
I/flutter (15351): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15351): The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (15351): HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111
I/flutter (15351): 
I/flutter (15351): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (15351): #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
I/flutter (15351): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (15351): #1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
I/flutter (15351): #2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter (15351): #3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter (15351): #4      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
I/flutter (15351): #5      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:38:29)
I/flutter (15351): #6      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:323:11)
I/flutter (15351): #10     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:315:16)
I/flutter (15351): #11     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1010:20)
I/flutter (15351): #12     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:967:5)
I/flutter (15351): #13     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4376:12)
I/flutter (15351): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #25     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #26     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #29     _ListTileElement._mountChild (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:999:30)
I/flutter (15351): #30     _ListTileElement.mount (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:1013:5)
I/flutter (15351): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #35     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #36     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #45     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #46     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #48     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #49     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #51     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #52     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #54     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #56     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #57     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #58     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #60     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #61     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #63     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #64     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #65     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #66     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
I/flutter (15351): #67     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #68     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #70     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #72     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #73     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #74     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #76     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #77     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #80     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #84     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #85     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #86     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #88     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #89     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #90     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #91     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
I/flutter (15351): #92     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #93     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #95     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #96     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #97     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #98     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #99     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #101    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #102    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #103    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #104    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
I/flutter (15351): #105    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #106    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #107    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #108    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #109    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #110    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #111    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #112    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #113    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #114    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #115    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #117    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (15351): #118    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #119    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #120    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #121    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #122    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #123    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #124    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #125    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #126    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #127    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #128    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #129    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #130    ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4617:11)
I/flutter (15351): #131    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #133    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #134    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #135    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #136    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
I/flutter (15351): #137    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (15351): #138    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #140    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (15351): #141    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (15351): #142    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (15351): #143    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload%5C500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (4) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5CCapture.PNG
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (5) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5C1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (6) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5C0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (7) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5Cdownload%20(1).jfif
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15351): [{id: 5ef73963f8f4f552704eb5fb, name: momen, desc: uni, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111}, {id: 5ef755aa9011f235d007d432, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef755bb9011f235d007d433, name: c11, desc: d11, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11}, {id: 5ef755e59011f235d007d434, name: c11, desc: d11, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11}, {id: 5ef755f39011f235d007d435, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef7567b215f705ec00d439a, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1}, {id: 5ef759d4167fb241b82fcfcd, name: newcat, desc: unimmm5n, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg}, {id: 5ef75ae8d313d64f4cecbfc5, name: c1, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\Capture.PNG}, {id: 5ef75f15231fcc4edc13b3b9, name: c1y, desc: d1, img: http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png}, {id: 5efa29ba17c0672b88fb6ae8, name: catauth, desc: auth cat desc, img: http://192.168.43.106:30
I/flutter (15351): #144    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (15351): #145    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (15351): #146    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1288:36)
I/flutter (15351): #147    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1273:20)
I/flutter (15351): #148    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2412:19)
I/flutter (15351): #149    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1266:11)
I/flutter (15351): #150    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter (15351): #151    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1823:58)
I/flutter (15351): #152    PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:875:15)
I/flutter (15351): #153    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1823:13)
I/flutter (15351): #154    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter (15351): #155    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
I/flutter (15351): #156    RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:78:12)
I/flutter (15351): #157    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #158    RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:134:11)
I/flutter (15351): #159    RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:373:11)
I/flutter (15351): #160    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #161    RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:410:13)
I/flutter (15351): #162    RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1367:12)
I/flutter (15351): #163    RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1285:20)
I/flutter (15351): #164    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #165    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (15351): #166    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #167    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (15351): #168    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #169    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (15351): #170    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter (15351): #171    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (15351): #172    RenderObject.layout
```

Comment: The url is wrong... 192.168.43.106:3000/upload\\ should be 192.168.43.106:3000/upload/. Where's that generated?

Comment: no it is right, and when i paste it wither in browser or in flutter Image.network, it give me the right image, this api is local api in my computer, and it is connected with mobile, and everything work well as i said, except url for image

Answer (score 1):

%5C is the problem see. whenever in dart you use '\something' here \ is the escape sequence that is the next to it is treated as special character. Now you have two \ so hence you know the Character value or encoded version of \ is 5C in hexcode.

So all you have to do is treat it as Raw string so get the string in `r''` and your work is done

All you can do is do some code get the url split strings. But that would be a long route
Hope this could help : )

Comment: can you please clarify how to solve it? i don't understand

Comment: use this in Image network url:  r'snapshot.data[index]['file'] '